# Standardized Error Codes - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, nserror

I'm trying to add error codes to one of my project like this:

```
typedef enum {
    FSChatErrorChatManagerInUse = 101,
    FSChatErrorFailedToRetrieveHeader = 202,
    FSChatErrorFailedToGetCount = 303,
} FSChatErrorCode;
```

Then, send:

```
NSError * err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Failed To Get Count"
                                    code:FSChatErrorFailedToGetCount
                                userInfo:nil];
```

So when notified of an error, you can see what kind it is:

```
if (err.code == FSChatErrorFailedToGetCount) {
    // do stuff
}
```

#### Question

Is there some sort of standard error code syntax or numbering I should follow?  I'm having a hard time finding a reference.

Comment: I can't recall anything of a general nature.

Comment: @HotLicks - So it doesn't really matter what number they are for something like this?  I know http error codes have some sort of standard like 404 not found.

Comment: If you plan to have more than a handful it's usually best to assign them in groups -- 100-199, 200-299, 300-399, eg, based on general category.

Comment: but http codes are `status code`s, so 2xx codes mean successful, 3xx codes mean redirection... http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [page](http://nshipster.com/nserror/) has a nice discussion of this subject:

> Like exit status codes, an NSError -code signals the nature of the
>   problem. These status codes are defined within a particular error
>   domain, in order to avoid overlap and confusion. These status codes
>   are generally defined by constants in an enum.
>
> For example, in the NSCocoaErrorDomain, the status code for an error
>   caused by NSFileManager attempting to access a non-existant file is 4,
>   as defined by NSFileNoSuchFileError. However, 4 in NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   refers to a POSIX EINTR, or "interupted function" error.

So, since you're using your own error domain, you can create whatever error codes you want. By the way, in your example you seem to be misusing the domain value: it's not meant to contain an error message.Use `userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]` for that.

Comment: What should be included in the domain?

Comment: "The error domain—this can be one of the predefined NSError domains, or an arbitrary string describing a custom domain." See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Error_Domains for a list of the predefined domains.

It's just a string (best defined as a constant) to limit the scope of your error codes.